# Procedure or Function 'ReadPortalPage' expects parameter '@Transactionref', which was not supplied

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, ado.net

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlconn))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("ReadPortalPage", conn))
                    {
                       // command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        conn.Open();
                        SqlParameter tranref = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transactionref", Transactionreference);
                        using (SqlDataReader datareader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                        {
                            while (datareader.Read())
                            {
                                xmlPath = datareader.GetString(0);
                                TshAmt = datareader.GetString(1);
                                TshPhno = datareader.GetString(2);
                            }
                            datareader.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

In above code i am getting error Procedure or Function 'ReadPortalPage' expects parameter '@Transactionref', which was not supplied. at sqlparameter.Could any one plz help me.

Comment: i think when you are passing the value to SP via `Transactionreference` it's getting the null value, that's why you are getting the Error.

Comment: yeah, ur right..but some times i may get error, some times i may get no errors, i didn't understand what is happening in this code.

Comment: then you have to use `@Transactionref ` as a optional parameter in SP.
set the value of `@Transactionref ` to null in your SP.

Comment: tell me datatype of `@Transactionref`??

Comment: it can't read data from db, it gives error at this line: SqlDataReader datareader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

Comment: put your SP code and update your question.

Comment: Transactionreference is null it seems

Comment: USE [ePayPort]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ReadPortalPage]    Script Date: 08/11/2015 09:58:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReadPortalPage]
@Transactionref NVARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT XmlData,PayAmt,CustomerPhone FROM TasheelData WHERE TransactionReference=@Transactionref
END

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have not added parameter to your command.

```
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@Transactionref";
param.Value         = Transactionreference;
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Another way

replace this line

`SqlParameter tranref = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transactionref", Transactionreference);`

with

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transactionref", Transactionreference);
```